# Странности с проектом Delphi - не изменяется позиционирование главной формы

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Началось всё с невозможности изменить иконку в проекте.
Теперь заметил, что я постоянно пододвигаю окно главной формы в центр, но при каждом новом открытии проекта она опять забивается в угол. Т.е. кто-то (какая-то неведомая сила) переписывает файл проекта .dfm
Что это такое и кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался? В ручную она прекрасно редактируется.
И главное всё изменяется, всё сохраняется, все параметры кроме положения.
Как такое возможно?

---

UPD: забыл указать, что Embedded Disigner отключен в VCL Designer в Options
Т.е. Интерфейс с откреплёнными формами, как в старом, добром Delphi 7

Comment: а что значит "при каждом новом открытии проекта она опять забивается в угол"? В XE реализован single-window интерфейс IDE, о каких углах речь?

Comment: и что там у вас про позионирование указано в свойствах формы?

Comment: @kami форма у него при запуске приложения не по центру открывается, а в углу экрана.

Comment: @teran тогда формулировка вопроса некорректна. Потому что "при каждом новом открытии проекта" ассоциируется с открытием проекта (dproj) в IDE, а никак не с запуском готового приложения.

Comment: @kami, забыл указать, что Embedded Disigner у меня отключен в VCL Designer в Options.
Т.е. интерфейс с откреплёнными формами, как в старом, добром Delphi 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решено!**
Заменил в настройках формы poScreenCenter на poDesigned - и сохранил, потом вернул poScreenCenter и всё. Форма проекта теперь там, где нужно.
P.S. Странно, почему эта настройка влияет на позицию формы в окне Delphi при разработке?